# Is there a way to find coverage of UI test cases?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage, ui-automation, xcode-ui-testing

I know how to check coverage of Unit test cases, we can see coverage for each `.swift` file in Xcode coverage report. but what about UI test cases?

As per my understanding, In unit test cases the subject being tested is a `.swift` file. if a file has class with 4 methods/functions. The unit test coverage of that file would be 100% only if all the 4 methods are being called from unit test cases.

In UI test cases the subject is the View, Does interacting with all the UI elements leads to 100% coverage? How does coverage report for UI test work?

**Edit:**
[image: Unit test - uncovered code]
In Unit tests - I know that when few lines of function are not covered I see red overlay, here I know that I have to write unit tests for `screenshot` class method, line 56 in above attached image. Is there any similar mechanism in UI tests?

In UI tests - How can we find which UI element is left uncovered?

Answer (score 0):

The code coverage report can be generated for both unit and UI tests in Xcode. In your testing scheme choose Gather coverage for required targets. You can only get coverage for targets in your workspace.

The way coverage report is collected for UI tests is the same as for unit tests.

Even if you interact with all UI elements in your app, some code might be uncovered by tests. If you aim to increase your coverage, add additional tests to execute previously uncovered code.

Comment: How does UI test coverage work? can you give a example with a simple view?

Comment: Imagine all your app code lines have breakpoints. When you interact with UI, you'll debug your application and will visit breakpoints. The number each line was "visited" will be counted

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of UI Test coverage report? A sample app with only one ui element would work.

Comment: More about coverage in Xcode https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/403/